# podman is running but still getting "Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed and running?

Tags: docker, podman, aws-sam-cli, podman-compose, podman-in-podman

I am running AWS lambdas written in java with podman but when I hit the sam command it is throwing "Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed and running?"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SAM uses the DOCKER_HOST environment variable, so that needs to be set. (Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4329#issuecomment-1289588827)

You can follow these instructions (Windows/MacOS/Linux) to set that variable: https://podman-desktop.io/docs/migrating-from-docker/using-the-docker_host-environment-variable.